# django makemigrations: makemigrations add only id field from model

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and python and mongodb.
i tried to makemigrations myapp.
i get a 0001_initial.py but this file create Id field and not my model fields

This is my settings.py content:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapi.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'apidb',
    }
}
```

my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name: models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    last_name: models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

I'm looking for a solution, but I don't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just add equal to (=) instead of colon(:) in field defination in your models.py. Because of colon django is not registering them as a field.